# install gym on google coolab: metadata-generation-failed

Tags: google-colaboratory, metadata, openai-gym

I'm trying to install gym on a Google Colab notebook, however, I keep receiving the following error. How can I solve it?

google colab code

[image]

error message

[image]

I have tried everything, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears to be specific to the release version 0.21, which gets picked by default for some reason. Specifying the [gym release](https://github.com/openai/gym/releases) you need will see it installed without any further `gym error: metadata-generation-failed` hassles.

```py
!pip install gym==0.25.2 stable-baselines3
```

nJoy

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to downgrade the default setuptools and wheel versions.

```
!pip install setuptools==65.5.0 wheel==0.38.4
```

[This](https://github.com/huggingface/deep-rl-class/issues/300#issuecomment-1544119944) has addressed the same issue.